# Long boot time on Dell XPS 13 9350

Tags: boot, xubuntu, dell, 17.04, ahci

I installed Xubuntu 17.04 on my Dell XPS 13 9350. It looks like everything works fine except one thing. The boot time is more than 100 seconds. Here is the [dmesg output](https://gist.github.com/Lazin/d837dcbc295f0524bfb1166d8fd98db6). Scroll it to line 914:

```
[    4.192005] brcmfmac 0000:3a:00.0 wlp58s0: renamed from wlan0
[   93.322099] ACPI: Invalid package element [0]: got number, expecting [R]
```

This looks like something gets timed out during boot time. How can I fix this?

Update:

This is my systemd-analyze critical-chain output:

```
The time after the unit is active or started is printed after the "@" character.
The time the unit takes to start is printed after the "+" character.

graphical.target @1min 31.170s
└─multi-user.target @1min 31.170s
  └─hddtemp.service @1min 31.163s +7ms
    └─network-online.target @1min 31.162s
      └─NetworkManager-wait-online.service @1min 30.357s +805ms
        └─NetworkManager.service @1min 30.268s +82ms
          └─dbus.service @1min 30.258s
            └─basic.target @1min 30.255s
              └─sockets.target @1min 30.255s
                └─snapd.socket @1min 30.252s +2ms
                  └─sysinit.target @1min 30.227s
                    └─systemd-timesyncd.service @588ms +253ms
                      └─systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service @553ms +29ms
                        └─local-fs.target @551ms
                          └─run-user-1000-gvfs.mount @1min 38.072s
                            └─run-user-1000.mount @1min 37.656s
                              └─local-fs-pre.target @168ms
                                └─keyboard-setup.service @71ms +96ms
                                  └─systemd-journald.socket @69ms
                                    └─-.slice @61ms
```

**Update**

This is my `systemd-analyze blame` output:

```
      2.034s postfix@-.service
       806ms NetworkManager-wait-online.service
       719ms systemd-resolved.service
       696ms dev-nvme0n1p2.device
       239ms swapfile.swap
       179ms boot-efi.mount
       158ms lightdm.service
       155ms plymouth-quit-wait.service
       137ms accounts-daemon.service
       128ms ModemManager.service
       120ms systemd-timesyncd.service
       120ms networking.service
       113ms keyboard-setup.service
        96ms grub-common.service
        95ms apport.service
```

And this is a `systemd-analyze` output:

```
Startup finished in 6.874s (firmware) + 5.040s (loader) + 3.139s (kernel) + 3min 439ms (userspace) = 3min 15.494s
```

**Update 2**

This is how my `/etc/fstab` file looks like:

```
UUID=9207565d-3f73-4668-8f74-db0a07516111 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/nvme0n1p1 during installation
UUID=AED1-2DDE  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/mapper/cryptswap1 none swap sw 0 0
```

This is the actual partitions:

```
/dev/nvme0n1p2: UUID="9207565d-3f73-4668-8f74-db0a07516111" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="d55e7382-7e13-48a5-8c82-4c937dfdfbdd"
/dev/nvme0n1: PTUUID="dbc896e1-3755-4205-a707-34370ed01e5d" PTTYPE="gpt"
/dev/nvme0n1p1: UUID="AED1-2DDE" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI System Partition" PARTUUID="4a8ffbf3-d968-413f-bf54-7caaf099b8a2"
```

Comment: Add these two command outputs to your post: `systemd-analyze` and `systemd-analyze blame | head -15`

Comment: are you mounting any network drives?  `cat /etc/fstab`

Comment: No network drives, but I'm mounting something called /dev/mapper/cryptswap1 and /boot/efi, maybe this is a problem?

Comment: I think that's it, but to check you can run `ls /dev/mapper` and `cat /proc/swaps` to see if you are running a swap file and if it is encrypted. If you do not, then try to comment out the cryptswap line in fstab and see what happens. The EFI partition looks like it's there.

Comment: I commented out line in /etc/crypttab and /etc/fstab and it worked.

    $ systemd-analyze
    Startup finished in 12.997s (firmware) + 5.072s (loader) + 3.148s (kernel) + 2.996s (userspace) = 24.214s